# How to resolve compile error

Tags: typescript, q

After converting a js file to a ts file, I am getting this compile error:

```
Type '() => Promise<{}>' is not assignable to type 'Promise<{}>'.
Property 'fin' is missing in type '() => Promise<{}>'.
```

This is the code:

```
system.defer = function(action) {
    var deferred = Q.defer();
    action.call(deferred, deferred);
    var promise = deferred.promise;
    deferred.promise = function() { return promise; }; //Error here
    return deferred;
};
```

What is this error message saying?  What should I do to resolve?

This code comes from this [page](http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Q.html) which is a part of DurandalJS.

The code works.  If I comment it out, it breaks the app.  I am not sure what it is trying to do.

Comment: Why are you assigning a value to the deferred's `promise` property? It already has a value, changing it is not a good idea.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish on the line with the error? Like @DCoder said, what you have written doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Thanks for comments.  I am really not sure what it is trying to do, but it does work.  When commenting out, code breaks.  I added link to where I got the source code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the page which you linked to from `DurandalJS` it expects `jQuery` promises which you can swap with Q if you really want to.

The jQuery `deferred` expects a function `promise` (see [doc](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.promise/)) while `Q` has a property called `promise` so in order for DurandalJS to work correctly it requires it to be a function as that is what it expects.

You can fix the error you are having with a cast like below

```
deferred.promise = <any>function() { return promise; };
```

Comment: Ah, I get it now.  +1 for detailed answer.